# symfony2 injecting a dependence optimization

Tags: symfony, service, constructor, dependency-injection, repository

I have a form event subscriber which needs an entity repository.
I would like to inject this repository dependency ideally without having to use the constructors of the subscriber and its parents because this subscriber is needed in many different forms.

So basically I have the following chain :

Controller calls -> CustomManagerService instantiates-> Form instantiates -> EventSubscriber needs-> EntityRepository

the maanager is already a service. It is a pain both to transmit a constructor repository argument from the manager through the form to the subscriber and it is a pain to set each form as a service.

Why can't I instantiate the repository in the subscriber directly ? I have read it is a bad practice.

EDIT : this is what I have so far :

in my controller :

```
$unitRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UnitRepository');
$myManager = $this->get('my_manager')
$form = $myManager->createForm($unitRepository);
```

in myManager:

```
public function createForm(UnitRepository $unitRepository){
return $this->formFactory->createForm(
new xxxType($unitRepository)
}
```

in my form:

```
use MyBundle/AddUnitFieldSubscriber;
protected $unitRepository;

public function __construct(UnitRepository $unitRepository)
{
$this->unitRepository = $unitRepository;
}

public function buildform()
{
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddUnitFieldSubscriber($this->unitRepository));
}
```

in my subscriber:
    protected $unitRepository;

```
public function __construct(UnitRepository $unitRepository)
{
$this->unitRepository = $unitRepository;
}
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
$unitRepository = $this->unitRepository;
$unitRepository->doStuff()
}
```

I found this extremely lenghty, and sometimes I have a form calling a subform which is the one using the eventSubscriber. if I set the forms as services, I also sometimes get errors cause I am instantiating them without the required first constructur parameter.

What would be the shortest path to do it right and to not repeat all this knowing only the subscriber need access to the repository ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you show us your services definition?

Comment: Instantiating a repository requires access to the entity manager (I'm assuming you are using Doctrine 2).  So instantiating a repository directly in the subscriber won't help.  If a form needs additional services injected then you make the form a service.  It's easy enough once you have done a few.  You can also make the subscriber a service and inject it into the form.

Comment: @Cerad, do I need to make the form a service then? If I continue to instantiate the form in my Manager like new xxxType() without arguments, I have the feeling that it will throw an error, won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure I understood everything or even anything, but I'm going to try a response.

I would suggest you to define a service `SubscriberProvider` which will be responsible of the instantiation of the subscriber and the injection of the repository in the subscriber (via a setter of the subscriber). You could retrieve an instance of subscriber using a method `get`, `retrieve`, `create`, `provide` or whatever you prefer of the service `SubscriberProvider`. You could then inject this provider in another service.

**EDIT**

Here is the definition of the service related to your form type:

```
services:
    your_own_bundle.form.type.unit:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\Form\Type\UnitType
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: unit }
```

And its class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Your\OwnBundle\Event\AddUnitFieldSubscriber;

class UnitType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $unitRepository;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->unitRepository = $doctrine->getRepository('UnitRepository');
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(
            new AddUnitFieldSubscriber($this->unitRepository)
        );
    }
```

Then, you can use this type like that:

```
$builder->add('available_unit', 'unit', array());
```

This way, you don't have to pass the repository to your manager.

Comment: I have added full code example. Would your solution not be one more intermediary on top of those many ones I already have?

Comment: Set the code to get the repository in the provider. Set the form as a service. Inject the provider in the form service. Use the provider in the form to get an instance of `AddUnitFieldSubscriber`. This way you won't have the problem `I also sometimes get errors cause I am instantiating them without the required first constructur parameter`.

Comment: so far my form is being instantiated from the custom manager class with new xxxType($this->unitRepository). if I transform it into a service, I need to call in in my controller and pass it as an argument because doing new xxxType() in my manager class won't initiate the provider constructor argument ('error, provider expected, null given'). Am I right? and then it as complicated as before

Comment: I wrote some code for you. Note that I directly do the work in the form type so no need for a provider.

Comment: And if I call the form from outside a controller ? I have to pass the form as a constructor argument of the custom class or when instantiating the form in the custom class the doctrine argument won't be found. I was searching for a way for this subscriber to not depend on a constructor argument because it is being used in many forms.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you say, but if you want to use the form type in another class, you just have to define a service on this class and inject the service of your form type to this service thanks to the reference `@your_own_bundle.form.type.unit`. This way the dependency injection will work as expected. Never use a `new UnitType()` of course.

Comment: Well I understand, thanks. I find this all not very efficient. I need the subscriber in about 10 forms and this subscriber needs access to a repository. Now I have to define all forms as services or use the new xxType with an argument. I was hoping I could instantiate something and use a service inside more easily. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Remember that other form types can use your `UnitType`, just using `$builder->add('available_unit', 'unit', array());` in the method `buildForm` for example. So, you don't have to declare all the form using it as services.

Comment: Glad I could help you. If you do not need more advices you should probably valid the answer.